# How to select data from a table and save it in a variable in android

Tags: android, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the rows `amount` and `aid`. I need the sum of amounts which have a certain aid. The aid, I will be declaring in the android class. For example, I want to select the sum of amounts for aid 12. How can I do this? The problem is if I run an SQL command in the android class like this,

```
SQLiteDatabase dbq = openOrCreateDatabase("shareity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       dbq.execSQL("SELECT amount FROM donations WHERE activityid = aid");
```

i don't think this will succeed, coz the aid I  need is declared in the android class itself. Any help please?

Comment: why downvote? At least please answer if it's too simple for you. We beginners are asking these coz we don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
 dbq.execSQL("SELECT amount FROM donations WHERE activityid = aid");
```

You need to do this.

```
Cursor c = dbq.rawQuery("SELECT amount FROM donations WHERE activityid = 'aid'", null);
```

Edit : If aid is variable means you need to modify like this

```
Cursor c = dbq.rawQuery("SELECT amount FROM donations WHERE activityid = '"+aid+"'", null);
```

Read value from this cursor.

**Update 2**

Here you want the sum of amount column so change your query as follows.

```
Cursor c = dbq.rawQuery("SELECT sum(amount) FROM donations WHERE activityid = '"+aid+"'", null);
```

Here the condition is amount column is might Integer in your Create Table query.

Comment: I am trying to get the value from the cursor like this:
`if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
          idk = c.getString(0);
          Log.d("id", idk + "Id" );
         
      }`

and I am using the value of `idk`. It gives me a null value. Can you help me please?

Comment: It doesn't show an error. I used the value `idk`. And this returned null. I'm asking how to get the sum of the values from the amount field @Amsheer

Comment: You want sum of all the values in amount column right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76606/discussion-between-amsheer-and-yohan-blake).

Answer (score 1):

To select data from table, you have to execute the select query and it would return data in `cursor`. After that you have to iterate through the cursor to get the data.

P.S. I am giving you a ready code because there are plenty of resources available on the net, try to search and post comment if you will face any issue!

Comment: I am trying to get the value from the cursor like this:
`if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
          idk = c.getString(0);
          Log.d("id", idk + "Id" );
         
      }`

and I am using the value of `idk`. It gives me a null value. Can you help me please?